# why is the output of make_password different than expected?

Tags: python, django

Sorry if this is a dumb question, but I'm new to django here. I'm creating a signup flow, one that needs the users email id and password to create the user. I'm trying to hash and salt the password, before saving the salted password in the db, along with the email.

I'm using django's default `make_password(password=password, salt=get_random_string(length=32))` to hash and salt the password. But the output I get is like `"!KxPs6lAiW1Im2iuBbuK1lm6dqQz5h08gPSIWlEUr"` instead of being something like `"algorithm$iterations$salt$hash"`. Here's the code:

```
salt = get_random_string(length=32)
print(salt)
salted_pwd = make_password(password=password, salt=salt)
print("salted", salted_pwd)
```

Why is this happening and what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The exclamation point at the start of your hashed string indicates that this is an "unusable password" - one that will never match any user-entered password when attempting to log in.  You create such a hash by passing None as the `password` parameter to `make_password()`.  Check where that value is coming from, something has gone wrong prior to the code you've shown.

Comment: Likely `password` is `None`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Likely your password is `None`, as is specified in the [documentation <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/auth/passwords/#django.contrib.auth.hashers.make_password):

> If the password argument is None, an unusable password is returned (one that will never be accepted by `check_password()`).

This is *not* the same as an empty password: an unusable password can not be used to login in. Sometimes this means the user can log in through other means however, like an oauth backend, etc. So a user with an unusable password is *not* the same as an inactive user. If you decide to only log in through OAuth/LDAP/…, then all your users can have unusable passwords.